# Simple Percentage formula claculation

Tags: percentage

Morning all

I need calculate a percentage in excel 2010

I have cell R15 as 17% 
I have cell F15 as 197

How do I calculate 17% of 197 with a formula?

Very simple I know but I am useless

Thanks

Danny

Comment: @Jens Excel Formula are [actually generally considered on-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261875/3725745) for Stack Overflow. However this particular question shows close-to-zero research effort. Daniel, did you even _try_ to solve this yourself? It really is as simple as `=R15*F15`.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both cells:

=F15*R15

If you wrote only 197 and 17 (without % symbol) do the following:

=F15*R15/100

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel percentages are stored as decimals so 75% is actually stored as 0.75.

Given this you should be able to multiply the 2 together to get the result

197 x .17 = 33.49

or =(F15*R15)